# php check username + need variable case insensitive to register in database

Tags: php, mysql, case

I have a file register.php for my site.

```
$username=filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$sql="SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?";
$stmt=$con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$stmt->close();
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    if(empty($row->username)) {
        echo "different username. IS OK !!";
    } else {
        echo "<font color='red'>*</font>".$username."<font color='red'> : this username already exist in DB!!</font><br />";
    }   
}
```

Here I compare the ($username from form) with ($row->username from DB)
$row->username exist only if $username is already register. So, if this exist, will go on ELSE part.
If $row->username doesn't exist (is empty) , because SELECT from sql will find no attribute, my code must go on IF part and display this message "different username. IS OK !!"

**Why IF part doesn't work?** I know sql will return 0, or NULL or "" or something like this. If I put a username which is not already registered, the code don't show the specific message. Because in this part I want to change the message with the code which permit to register new username.

empty($row->username) is not really empty if SQL can't find something to return?

Another problem is : I have a registered username "Test". MySQL is not case-sensitive, but in php, I can register another username "test". The code in php will run as a new register, but in MySQL nothing will happening because "username is unique" there. So, in "check username" from above, I need to check 2 insensitive variables ($username and $row->username). Because if in DB I have Test, and I want to register new user "test", this code will let me to do it. I want to show a error message if this happening.

Comment: compare your form variable `$username` by casting it into lowercase using `strtolower($your_variable)` function then you can check it with database value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to verify if no rows are returned.

```
$username=filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$sql="SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?";
$stmt=$con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->num_rows;
if ($count == 0) {
    // Username not in table
} else {
    // Username already exists
]
```

To be sure that all your usernames are lowercase, simply convert it to lowercase before inserting it.

```
$username = strtolower($username);
```

Comment: `rowCount()` is PDO, they're using the mysqli_ api. Edit: this comment as per original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44413209/1 to which you're still using PDO's `>rowCount()`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks, I should've seen that.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should covert your database and php variable into same case then compare it for checking.

```
$username=filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$sql="SELECT LCASE(username) AS username FROM users WHERE username=?";
$stmt=$con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', strtolower($username)); // used strtolower();
$stmt->execute();
```

Try this code, hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

thanks for fast answers. Honestlly, I don't know where was the issue, because now it's run perfect, without strtolower method. This is my code now:

```
$sql="SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?";
$stmt=$con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_object();
$stmt->close();
if(empty($row->username)) {
    // if a cell from below is empty, go on ELSE part
    if (!empty($username) && !empty($password) && !empty($email) && !empty($country)) {
        $sql="INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, borned, gender, country, phone, register_date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?, now())";
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $username, $password, $email, $borned, $gender, $country, $phone);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        header ("Location: login.php");
    } else { 
        echo "<font color='red'>*Must complete required cells !!</font> ";
    }
// end of register dates
} else {
        echo "<font color='red'>*</font>".$username."<font color='red'> : this username already exist in DB!!</font><br />";
}
```

I have user "Test", if try to register "test" will give a message that the user is already registered.

Thanks again, the thread can be deleted is somebody consider that can not help somebody :D